# Django-Registration Admin Access

Tags: django-registration

I have Django-registration up and running. It seems to work quite well. It allows me to register/login then redirects me to /accounts/profile/.

However, I want registered users to access the Admin. I can redirect /accounts/profile to admin/ but my users cannot login, they need staff status to be set. Would I do this via a signal? Im not very familiar with them.

Also, when a user registers, i want them to have a profile with a lot more details. How do I extend this. I am not sure if i want to extend the User or extend the DjangoRegistration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked into this a lot. And while i think its possible I don't think this is the way it is designed.

It is designed to give you admin access, but then use the is_authenticated decorator on views. It works very well actually.